# Tensorflow Life cycle of a node;

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

when two variables are being evaluated TensorFlow,it is not supposed to reuse the values from the previous evaluation.(This is what was mentioned in Hands on Machine learning with sklearn and tensorflow by Aurélien Géron)

```
w = tf.constant(5)
x = w + 5
y = x**2 + 5
z = x**2 + 5
```

Take the piece of code mentioned above for example.
y and z should have the same value, if x is not modified in between their evaluation.
But I tried modifying their vales in-between the evaluation and still they have the same results.

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    a = y.eval()
    x = w + 3
    b = z.eval()
```

I am sorry if this is a really dumb question, but I just wanted to get my basics clear, it would really helpful if someone took time to explain this. Thanks

```
print(a) 
# 366
print(b)
# 366
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your doubts, in your code,

```
w = tf.constant(5)
x = w + 5
y = x**2 + 5
z = x**2 + 5
```

just creates a computation graph until you create a `session`, even the variables are not initialized yet.

In the following code,

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    a = y.eval()
    x = w + 3
    b = z.eval()
```

Once the session opened, It takes care of placing all the operations into the device you are computing with ( CPU or GPU). And it holds all the variables inside it.

Inside the Session, once `eval` is called Tensorflow automatically determines the nodes that it depends, and evaluates these nodes first, to explain you with both the scenario you have taken.

**1. a = y.eval()**

Here y is dependent on x and x is dependent on w, so it evaluates w first and evaluates x to calculate y.

2. **b = z.eval()**

Here z is dependent on x and x is dependent on w, once again from start it evaluates w first and evaluates x to calculate z. ***It does not reuse the result of x and w from eval done on y***.

In both the eval the nodes are selected by Tensorflow for value x is the first instance.

Below is the Graph representation of computation. Where you can see the second x declaration is not part of the graph(right corner).

[image]

if you want to run the computation in the order you can use `sess.run()` instead of `eval()`.

When `sess.run()` called, this method completes one set of computations in our graph in the following manner: it starts at the requested output(s) and then works backward, computing nodes that must be executed according to the set of dependencies.

Below is the modified example with the desired result.

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.constant(5)
x = w + 5
y = x**2 + 5
x = w + 3
z = x**2 + 5


with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  # a = y.eval()
  # init.run()
  # b = z.eval()
  print(sess.run(z))
  print(sess.run(y))
```

**Output:**

```
 69
105
```

You can notice when `sess.run(z)` is requested, while going backward immediate x value is  `x = w + 3` , similarly for `sess.run(y)`, while doing backward computation immediate x value  is `x = w + 5`.